# Convert jpg string to image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a jpg strign stored in "(string)HttpContext.Current.Session["image" + 0];" that I am trying to convert to a System.Drawing.Image.

I know the string is correct, because when I do this -

```
img.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["image" + 0];
```

Everying works as intended.

But when I do this -

```
 string inputString = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["image" + 0];
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            }
```

I get and error telling me the format is incorrect when trying to create an image from the stream.

Please help

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. Maybe there's something about the image you're trying to convert?

Comment: Can you provide a sample image?

Comment: the image is created on the client side with ajax like this - 
                var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
                image = image.replace('data:image/webp;base64,', '');
                            data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',

I sen this data to the server using ajax

Comment: Here's my image string - 
https://justpaste.it/1m3q8

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter converted it with no problem so I really don't understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

don't you need to convert webp to jpg/png first?
 for example [WebP-wrapper](https://github.com/JosePineiro/WebP-wrapper)

```
    using (WebP webp = new WebP())
    {
      var image = webp.Decode(imageBytes );
    }
```

Comment: This might be it but I can't find a webp wrapper that works in asp web. Each one I've tried tells me there is a dll missing and the one you pointed to references Forms so it's no good.

Comment: @Sen - works for me using  byte[] rawWebP = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/images/test.webp"));
                using (WebPWrapper.WebP webp = new WebPWrapper.WebP())
                {
                    var image = webp.Decode(rawWebP);
                }

Comment: I added https://github.com/JosePineiro/WebP-wrapper/blob/master/WebPTest/WebPWrapper.cs, libwebp_x64.dll, and libwebp_x86.dll (for dll's - under properties - Copy to output directory - always)

Comment: @SenSorokin - in WebPWrapper, remove calls to MessageBox.Show